# "mc.local is currently unable to handle this request" not able to find issue for error 500?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, centos, centos6

I am trying to setup a local environment for work in a Wordpress project. The server is running in a VM under Vmware Workstation and has CentOS 6.7, PHP 7.0.3, Apache 2.2.15 and MariaDB 10.0.23.

- I have Apache configured to work with VirtualHost, this is the one for the Wp Site:

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName mc.local

      DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mischiquiticos/site
      DirectoryIndex index.php

      <Directory /var/www/html/mischiquiticos/site>
          Options FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride All
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
      </Directory>

      ErrorLog logs/mc.local-error_log
      CustomLog logs/mc.local-access_log combined
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- I have configured WP to log every error using `WP_DEBUG` constant:

  ```
  define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
  define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
  define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
  @ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );
  define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', false );
  define( 'SAVEQUERIES', true );
  ```
- Since I am calling the site from a Windows host (where the Vmware is installed) then I have added this line to `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file:

  ```
  192.168.3.120   mc.local
  ```
- Finally I setup directory permissions & owner as follow:

  ```
  chown -R apache:root /var/www/html/mischiquiticos && find /var/www/html/mischiquiticos -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 2775 && find /var/www/html/mischiquiticos -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0664
  ```

Having that info here comes the problem: any time I try the URL `http://mc.local` I run into a 500 error with the following message:

> mc.local is currently unable to handle this request

Obviously something is wrong but I am not able to find what is failing since:

- `/var/log/httpd/logs/mc.local-error_log` => isn't logging anything meaning file is 0 bytes
- `/var/log/php_errors.log` => isn't logging anything meaning file is 0 bytes
- `/var/www/html/mischiquiticos/site/wp-content/debug.log` => the file isn't being created

My first though was PHP version since it's new and Wordpress could not support it but the funny about this is I have 4 wordpress sites running on the same server and all of them work so PHP version is not the issue.

I am out of ideas on this so I need some new ones in order to find where the issue is, any idea? What else I could do in order to get some helpful info?

Comment: What happens if you try directly with the IP address?